# avoiding redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain

Depending on the subdomain I want to call a specific controller.

What I currently do:
My page uses the subdomain to identify users like `username.site.com`. I get the username, look it up in the database and render the appropriate data in the `UsernamesController`.

the only exception to this is www.site.com or site.com . In that case another controller should be called. I currently do this by detecting the `www` or `''` subdomain in `ApplicationController and then redirecting. Although I feel that a redirect is not in it's place here.

Someone has another approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[subdomains_routes](http://github.com/mholling/subdomain_routes) allows you to define custom routes based on current subdomain.